# How to draw filled arcs in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a figure like the one attached here. These curves are parabolic like and I would like to fill in colors in between. Any ideas in TiKZ?
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A draw base on the picture using `Parabola Operation`

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [red!30,rotate=-90] 
(0,0) parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(2,0) 
-- ++(0.3,0.2) 
parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(-2.6,0) 
-- cycle;
\draw [rotate=-90] 
(0,0) parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(2,0) 
++(0.3,0.2) parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(-2.6,0);
\fill [blue!30,rotate=-90] 
(-0.3,0.2) parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(2.6,0) 
-- ++(0.4,0.2) 
parabola[parabola height=2.05cm] ++(-3.4,0)
-- cycle;
\draw [rotate=-90] 
(-0.3,0.2) parabola[parabola height=2cm] ++(2.6,0) ++(0.4,0.2) 
parabola[parabola height=2.05cm] ++(-3.4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]